# Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1

Tags: 14.04, boot, wireless, broadcom

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS` and the boot getting the following warning:

```
Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1
```

Using the following command at terminal

```
$ dmesg | grep b43
```

getting the following output:

```
[   36.226712] Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1
[   36.226716] b43: probe of bcma0:0 failed with error -524
```

I'd highly appreciate if you help me to figure out this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edited**

Found this [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93738/119307) for `linux` but don't know how to use this approach in `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS`.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300 [1028:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge


$ dpkg -l | grep linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and also `dpkg -l | grep linux-firmware-nonfree` terminal commands.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 for your interest in my problem. I editted the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest installing Broadcom wl driver for this chip.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If you choose to keep b43, you can edit that file in /etc/modprobe.d/ in Ubuntu too.

But wl should be more stable.

**But if everything works there is no need to worry**

Comment: (+1) Thanks a lot @Pilot6. Works like a charm.